# JPanel repaint misbehaves

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

After calling `repaint()` on a `JPanel` out of an `ActionListener` for a `JCheckBox`, the `JPanel` has some...issues...they fix themselves upon minimizing and restoring but that's a hassle for my clients. **Any ideas on how to fix this?**

[image]

**Code is below**

```
            JCheckBox curr = new JCheckBox(choices.get(a));
            curr.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    //System.out.println(((JCheckBox)e.getSource()).getText());
                    if (specs.getSelectedItem()!=null&&!specs.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        String strSpec = specs.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (strSpec.matches("\\w+\\s\\w+"))
                        {
                            Time x = GraphCreator.parseTime(strSpec);
                            GC.getGraph(x);
                            GC.getGraph(x, new Team(((JCheckBox)e.getSource()).getText()));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            GC.getGraph(new Team(((JCheckBox)e.getSource()).getText()),strSpec.trim());
                        }
                    }
                    pane.repaint();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you show some code where you call to repaint()? Maybe your ActionListener's code?

Comment: sorry about that just didn't think it would be that much help :\

Comment: No worries. You never know though. :)

Comment: How many classes do you have? If there isn't much code, http://justpaste.it/ to me and I'll take a look. Otherwise you can try using repaint(0,0,pane.getWidth(),pane.getHeight()); although that should really be the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pane.validate()` and `pane.repaint()` could work. However that's only when you are adding and removing components that will cause the layout to be affected/altered.

Comment: same thing it didn't do anything against the artifact in the corner. :\

Comment: actually it's fixed with repaint called on the jframe. odd I know but it seems to have worked. this.repaint(10,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

Comment: Is the 10ms necessary? Calling repaint() on the parent component, ie. your JFrame is a clever idea. Try just simply repaint()?

Answer (score 1):

trick should be

```
pane.revalidate();
pane.repaint();
```

Comment: tried them and nothing it still gives me that annoying artifact in the corner.

Comment: @if_zero_equals_one 1) you forgot to remove some Jcomponent(s), 2) you have to some issiue with LayoutManager http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html , 3) be sure that anything without seeing your code (very short runnable code) is only shots to the dark